# Conversion to HTML5

Tags: html

I have some web apps and I have converted the UI to HTML5. With XHTML Transitional, there were a lot of errors when validating. When I converted the pages to HTML5, most of the errors were reduced and I managed to make the web apps fully validated.

My question is, may this may arise any problems on some browsers. I tested some of the pages which I converted in all major browsers, being IE8, IE7, IE6, Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari and everything seems to be working well.

I am not using any features of HTML5 like canvas and so on. So there shouldn't be any problems with old browsers right? I converted to HTML5 so the web apps would be of the latest version known to the web and most importantly, they would validate correctly.

Is there any problems which might arise which I should be aware of?

P.S. By converting to HTML5, I mean that I changed the doctype from the usual transitional or strict one to just:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many browsers still do not understand the <article>,<header>,<footer>,<section> tags. If you are not using them, there will be no problems.

If you are using them, do like this:

CSS:

```
header,footer,section,article,nav,aside (and every other HTML5 block tag) {
  display:block;
}
```

Javascript:

```
document.createElement("article");
document.createElement("header");
document.createElement("footer");
// do so for the rest of the HTML 5 tags.
```

Comment: The most important browsers that don't recognize HTML5 yet are older versions if IE. You can fix that by using: http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

Comment: I am not using such elements. As I said, I switched just to doctype. That is why everything is still working then. In fact, I found an interesting article which at one point explains exactly this: http://diveintohtml5.org/semantics.html

Comment: This is the part I'm referring to: 

That happens to be one of the 15 doctypes that trigger “standards mode” in all modern browsers. There is nothing wrong with it. If you like it, you can keep it. Or you can change it to the HTML5 doctype, which is shorter and sweeter and also triggers “standards mode” in all modern browsers.

This is the HTML5 doctype:

<!DOCTYPE html>

That’s it. Just 15 characters. It’s so easy, you can type it by hand and not screw it up.

Comment: @Chris - Note that the diveintohtml5 page is referring to XHTML 1.0 **STRICT**. That, like the HTML5 doctype is standards-mode giving so in that change you won't get any problems. Your question mentions XHTML **TRANSITIONAL** however, and that is a limited-quirks-mode giving doctype, so you may get problems related to that switch over. The difference lies in the default vertical-alignment of some inline elements.

Answer (score 2):

As Jannis said old browsers don't recognize the new html elements.

If you want to apply the best practice for cross-browser compatibility check this link:

http://html5boilerplate.com/

Answer (score 0):

There is a DRY-solution for the new tags:
https://code.google.com/p/html5shim/